# ViewModel populates CollectionView Observable ok on initial entry, but adds in same method cause UIKit error

Tags: maui

.Net 8, Maui, iOS

In my view model, I have this:

```
public partial class CheckListViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    public ObservableCollection<CheckList> checkLists = new ObservableCollection<CheckList>();
...
```

I populate this on ContentPage_NavigatedTo referred to in the view.

```
    public async Task LoadCheckLists()
    { 
        await using (DatabaseContext dc = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            var TempCheckList = await dc.GetAllAsync<CheckList>().ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (TempCheckList != null)
            {
                foreach (CheckList checklist in TempCheckList.ToList())
                {
                    
                    //Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread...  This says it's deprecated and to use BindableObject.Dispatcher.Dispatch() instead

                        CheckList item = CheckLists.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == checklist.Id);
                        if (item == null)
                        {
                            CheckLists.Add(checklist);
                        }
                        else if (item != null)
                        {
                            CheckLists.Remove(item);
                            CheckLists.Add(checklist);

                        }
                }
            }
        }
```

The method works with no issues.  When the user navigates to the page below to add a new checklist which saves it to the DB and refers back.  This method is run again.  The item=null will not (and is not) hit at this point.  The issue is with the CheckLists.Add(checklist), or at least I think it is.  The debugger isn't allowing me to step through to be exact.  But then it crashes with:

```
UIKit Consistency error: you are calling a UIKit method that can only be invoked from the UI thread.
```

First, it doesn't make sense that this populates the list the first time, but then the second time through (adding additional items created from the add page and pulled from the DB).  But when I cannot seem to find the BindableObject.Dispatcher.Dispatch() on "this".

So two questions, why is this occurring?  I understand that the error is referring to adding the item from another thread other than the main thread, but it works the first time through.  The second time through is calling this method the same way as the first time through.  And secondly, how do I get past this error?

Answer (score 1):

When you first load the data, you're likely still on the main thread. However, when you fetch data asynchronously (e.g., from the database) and then try to update the UI, you might be on a background thread. First of all, you have to determine which Thread calling the method in different times.

Add this line of code to see in which Thread this method is executed :

```
if (Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground)
{

}
```

To ensure that you're updating the UI on the main thread, use Dispatcher.Dispatch method.

```
public async Task LoadCheckLists()
{
    await using (DatabaseContext dc = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        var TempCheckList = await dc.GetAllAsync<CheckList>().ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (TempCheckList != null)
        {
            Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
            {
                foreach (CheckList checklist in TempCheckList.ToList())
                {
                    CheckList item = CheckLists.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == checklist.Id);
                    if (item == null)
                    {
                        CheckLists.Add(checklist);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CheckLists.Remove(item);
                        CheckLists.Add(checklist);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's sometimes setbacks like this that cause me to step back and reconsider how I'm writing code.  Instead of switching to a new page to enter information, I made the selection page editable which is actually pretty darn cool. Unfortunately, that means I won't be able to test the above code right now but I'm sure I'll run into it again in the future.